# Searching for names in list - Sicstus Prolog

Tags: prolog

I've recently started messing round with Prolog but have hit a stumbling block with lists.

Let's say I have a list `[dom,is,a,man,jane,is,a,woman,mary,is,a,woman]` and I want to create a new list of womans names `[jane,mary]`. How would I go about doing this? I assume I'd have to search through the list for any X that is followed by `is,a,woman` but I have no idea how to achieve this. I've been googling for hours to no avail. I would post code if I had any :s

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which "algorithm" (well, in a declarative meaning) did you think about? Because, you know, it is important for us to be sure that our answer won't prevent you to think about your class assignment...

Comment: I would think it more prolog-y to iterate through a list of facts -- i.e. `[woman(mary),man(dom),woman(jane)]` so that the predicate implies that mary is a woman. Is this list of words a constraint?

Comment: "Googling for hours" for an answer without learning the language and spending time trying some things isn't an optimum path to learn. This isn't a very elegant scenario, but rolling with it for a moment, you wouldn't "search through the list" for things like `is,a,woman`, which is an imperative way to look at it. If your list structure really is that strict, you could (albeit inflexibly), for example, use a pattern such as `[X,is,a,woman|T]` to select a woman from the front of the list and recurse on `T`.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. Btw its not for a class assignment, I'm just trying to learn prolog :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always when describing lists, consider using DCGs. For example:

```
men_women([], [])     --> [].
men_women(Ms, [W|Ws]) --> [W,is,a,woman], men_women(Ms, Ws).
men_women([M|Ms], Ws) --> [M,is,a,man], men_women(Ms, Ws).
```

Example query and its result:

```
?- phrase(men_women(_, Ws), [dom,is,a,man,jane,is,a,woman,mary,is,a,woman]).
Ws = [jane, mary] ;
false.
```

This DCG also works for very general queries, such as:

```
?- length(Ls, _), phrase(men_women(_, Ws), Ls).
Ls = [], Ws = [] ;
Ls = [_G376, is, a, woman], Ws = [_G376] ;
Ls = [_G376, is, a, man], Ws = [] ;
Ls = [_G376, is, a, woman, _G388, is, a, woman], Ws = [_G376, _G388] .
```

Comment: Wow I'd never even come across DCGs before. Thanks mat! This looks great, may take me a while to fully understand it though

Answer (score 1):

```
% end once the input is empty
find_gender([], _, []).

% Compare the first 4 "entries" in the list.
% Name and Gender are variables, b/c they are written in upper case.
% 'is' and 'a' are atom.
% If the pattern matches, prepend the Name to the results.
find_gender([Name,is,a,Gender|Tail], Gender, [Name|Names]) :-
    % Find further Names in the Tail of the input list.
    find_gender(Tail, Gender, Names).

% The person is not of that Gender.
% You don't need to catch the Name here, b/c it won't be used. 
find_gender([_,is,a,X|Tail], Gender, Names) :-
    X \= Gender, % otherwise you would have wrong results when backtracking
    find_gender(Tail, Gender, Names).

% This is your usage example:
find_women(List, Names) :-
    find_gender(List, woman, Names).
find_men(List, Names) :-
    find_gender(List, man, Names).
```

The reverse works as well:

```
?- find_women(List, [jane,marry]).
List = [jane, is, a, woman, marry, is, a, woman] ;
false.
```

If your input list could contain other data, as in `[jane,owns,a,car,jane,is,a,woman,the,car,is,red]`, then you could simply drop entries until you find your pattern again by adding this clause:

```
find_gender([_|T], Gender, Names) :-
    find_gender(T, Gender, Names).
```

But this will cause you to have multiple results when backtracking, with some names omitted. You might want to introduce cuts (`!`) in the first clauses in that case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kay. I've been working through it and trying to understand it. Trying out you're example for a list that might contain extra data such as [jane,owns,a,car,jane,is,a,woman,the,car,is,red] doesn't seem to work. Even with the last clause you added. Prologue says no! Can't figure it out, any ideas? Thanks =)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `Gender` parameter. Fixed now.